# git branch merge, changes in both side

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I have two branches in my git repo, master and develop.

Initially my develop and master was same , but later both branches changed, currently I need to merge both , I need both update in my master branch. How can I achieve it using merge functionality

Comment: It sounds like you simply want to combine both branches into master so that all updates are in master? checkout master and then merge in develop. git checkout master then git merge develop

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found there is no option to merge both updates, make master to old state and update develop with master update too..., then merge